# Couldnt read archive xib

Tags: iphone

I got an error in xib like couldnt read archive in xib. I searched in google for the solution but not got  any solution and also i am getting the entitlements.plist string as empty. Why it shows this.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not giving the name of the xib correctly while loading it.

Comment: it will create automatically when we will create a new class and select xib file.

Comment: it does if the name of the class and xib are same. Otherwise it doesn't and you will have to give the name.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SVN, then this error comes when your nib file is conflicted (i mean you and some other developer both have committed on the same file).

Comment: SVN is actually a tool by which many developers can work on same code in a project.
firstly u tell me that what is ur exact problem friend???
i am trying to help because i had this problem too.

Comment: @fayaz-> try to add new nib fayaz. actually ur nib gets corrupted, i think that's why it is not readable.

Comment: i tried every thing. but same error message is coming. please see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203734/read-archive-in-xib-in-xcode-3-2-4